# how to resample a mp3 audio with the length unchanged in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have thousands of mp3 audios to process. First these files should been normalized to 44.1kHz and coded over 16 bits in .wav mono format.

I tried `mp3read()` and `wavwrite()` to process(`wavwrite()` can set the sampling rate), and I also tried the `resample()` function. However, if the sampling rate of an audio is smaller than 44.1kHz, after this processing the length of the audio will been shortened, vice versa. For example, a 44kHz 4 minutes audio resampled to 22kHz, it  will become 8 minutes. How can I fixed the length of the audio and reample it?

English is not my native language, please forgive for mine grammar error and inaccurate terms. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is even though you were resampling it to the new Fs, you were saving it at the old Fs.

Here is 4 lines of code which:
- loads in a wav file. 
- Gets its sampling frequency (FsOld)
- Resamples it to the desired sampling frequency (FsNew)
- Saves it as a new wav file at the new sampling frequency.

```
[yOld, FsOld] = audioread('audio.wav');
FsNew = 44100;
yNew = resample(yOld,FsNew, FsOld);
audiowrite('audioNew.wav', yNew, FsNew);
```

All the Best..